# Limit SQL Server column to a list of possible values

Tags: sql-server, database, constraints

How do I put a constraint on a column so that it can only contain the following values? What do you call this type of constraint?

```
Allowed values: "yes", "no" or "maybe"
Column Data Type: nvarchar(5)
DBMS: SQL Server 2008
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

you can use a **CHECK** constraint

```
ALTER TABLE <table>
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_val CHECK (col in ('yes','no','maybe'))
```

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: How can i do it in SSMS table constructor?

Answer (score 20):

Yes, check a constraint is it what you need.
You can declare check constraint at the table declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    _id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    decision NVARCHAR(5),
    CHECK (decision in ('yes','no','maybe'))
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using enumeration table is a way to go.

Comment: newbies might not know what is meant by "enumeration table". An example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

2021 here, I wonder if we can do this in another way (not necessarily a better way compared to check constraints).

For the column that only allows for "yes", "no" or "maybe" values maybe we can have a column with bit type and then have a computed column next to it like

```
Create Table xxx (
ColumnName bit null,
ColumnNameDerived varchar(10) as 
    case ColumnName
        when 0 then 'no'
        when 1 then 'yes'
        else 'maybe'
    end
)
```

For column with more possible values maybe choose tinyint type and then with a check constraint like "<= 10". Say a column has 10 possible values then a constraint "< 10" will do.

so the constraint will not be too long to read and immediately you know how many possible values are there. This can help save storage too.

Comment: Although this would work, it adds a level of complexity and obfuscation that isn't necessary to get the job done.  There are better ways that are more maintainable and easier for developers to comprehend.  If the enumerated values were in the 10's or 100's or 1000's, then maybe, but a foreign key to an enumeration table would still be better for clarity's sake.